# How can I get swipe gestures on webview in react-native?

Tags: react-native, webview

I am developing an app in react native and unfortunately I'm stuck in getting swipe action on webview. I'm trying to get browser's swipe action but don't know how can i do it.

Comment: Hi, I got its answer by using this npmjs.com/package/react-native-swipe-gestures we can swipe anything inside this pacakge's element in render function.